# chosen search input with 8.200 dropdown result very slow on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, jquery-chosen

I have wordpress with a chosen search input with 8.200 dropdown results very slow, Is there any solution?
Or perhaps it would be possible to limit on php to 100 the results to be displayed and searched in the search field.

php used to display the field:

```
<div class="fre-input-field">
                    <label class="fre-field-title" for="project-location"><?php _e('Location (optional)', ET_DOMAIN);?></label>
                    <?php
                        ae_tax_dropdown( 'country' ,array(
                                'attr'            => 'data-chosen-width="100%" data-chosen-disable-search="" data-placeholder="'.__("Choose country", ET_DOMAIN).'"',
                                'class'           => 'fre-chosen-single',
                                'hide_empty'      => false,
                                'hierarchical'    => true ,
                                'id'              => 'country',
                                'orderby'   => 'id',
                                'order'     => 'ASC',
                                'show_option_all' => __("Choose country", ET_DOMAIN)
                            )
                        );
                    ?>
                </div>
```

thank in advance!

I have tried to clear the cache but it is still just as slow, it takes like 10 seconds to load the results in the dropdown and the users leave the page due to this.

Comment: Are you fetching /showing these 8 200 elements at once? What for?

Comment: The theme is configured like this, but I don't really need it to show everything, maybe it would be better to limit the list it shows to 10 or maybe a condition that shows only matches when you enter some characters in the search field, but I don't know how to do it. I tried the option to add: 'number' => '52' but it doesn't work for me because if I write it only searches among those 52 results and not among the total